# How to get MemoryUsage statistics for a java Process object

Tags: java, windows

Is it possible to get the current RAM usage of a java [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) that is created with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...);`. I am creating a minecraft server instance and I need to monitor the resource usage of the server.

Here is exactly how I am creating the process.

```
private void runStartCommand(){
    try {
        lines = new ArrayList<>();
        String cmd = "cmd.exe /c cd " + service.getLocation() + "& java -jar -Xmx2G -Xms2G "+service.getLocation()+"spigot-1.9.2.jar";
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()),8*1024);
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
        running = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this server on Unix?

Comment: @SamuelToh He executes `cmd.exe` so he is under Windows

Comment: No. currently it is running on Windows on my computer and in the future it will run on Centos and Windows servers

Comment: Probably worth Googling for powershell commands to do something equivalent to unix's 'top' command then grep for the process.

http://superuser.com/questions/176624/linux-top-command-for-windows-powershell

Comment: Shelling out from Java to launch another Java process is... not such a great practice.  Better to add the other Java process as a dependency to your project, and start a new Thread that invokes its main() method.  This greatly reduces the JVM overhead, means you're not restricted to one OS, and makes it much easier to monitor and control the other process.

Comment: Any suggestions for how to do that with spigot or craftbukkit

Answer (score 2):

Bukkit already provides a custom plugin for [monitoring and managing Minecraft server performance](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/performance-monitor/) that should suit you perfectly.

Usually you would use something like Java Melody or a JMX console to monitor the application server process. You can also instrument and monitor it with the [built-in VisualVM](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/performance-monitor/).

Comment: Sounds like a great solution. +1 for it

Comment: What im doing is creating a Gaming Control Panel so adding a plugin be useful to me

Answer (score 0):

http://linux.die.net/man/1/dstat

if you are under linux, you can try dstat. We use it to take control over cpu, disk e ram usage

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run systeminfo but you should really consider not doing it from Java but running some other tool (your could use nagios) on the OS - that way your monitoring isn't dependent on the app you're running.

Comment: Im creating a control panel for multiple game servers so managing it within the control panel would be essential